# Does a upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 updates a (manual) GRUB installation to GRUB2?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, grub2

I have a Lenovo Ideapad S205, which has difficulties with GRUB2. Therefore I did a manual installation of GRUB 0.97. Will a upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 destroy my old GRUB or will it respect the custom installation?

Comment: Its very likely that during upgrade, installation may ask you to choose the grub, that whether to keep existing GRUB or installa "package-maintainers" version of GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether or not you removed the grub-pc package before, or just installed grub-legacy to the disk from another system ( like a rescue disk ).  If not, then it will be upgraded, and overwrite grub legacy.